# Entity Framework DataContext to Oracle Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

I'm currently developing an MVC4 application that has a local SQL Database, but also needs to connect to an Oracle database for some stuff...

Now, I have a experience with MVC and EF, but I lack knowledge of Oracle.

After quite a long morning searching and trial, error and help I managed to connect to the oracle database using the "regular" way of opening a new OracleConnection(connString) and execute SQL with OracleCOmmand. So I know my connectionstring is correct and the database is accessible.

I was hoping I could just create a DataContext class, and use my working connectionstring, and EF would work out of the box when I would do

```
using (var ctx = new OracleContext())
{
   var test = ctx.People.ToList();
}
```

However, now I get an error about a null returned from the "get_ProviderFactory". Are some extra steps neccesary to get EF to work?

If you need any extra information, I'd be happy to supply that!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need the [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) that supports EF.

Comment: @GriffeyDog I already installed those. I installed the 32bit versions, set my project to 32 bits. I have a variety of Oracle DLL's (Among which the Oracle.DataAccess Dll which I see a lot on SO posts) in the GAC. I also tried to add the DbProviderFactories node to my web.config just in case the install didn't change my machine.config properly. It came back with the message that invariant-name (Oracle.DataAccess.Client) was already taken so I think that I actually installed everything correctly. But I keep getting the error. Is there something else I could be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, I figured this one out... So here's my way of tackeling this for future reference...

First of, to test what went wrong with the dataproviders, I used this code somewhere in the beginning of my app:

```
DataTable dataTable = DbProviderFactory.GetFactoryClasses();
```

This gave me a DataTable to inspect. In the Rows-property it showed 5 different Dataproviders (OleDB, SQL etc), my number 5 was the Oracle Dataprovider I installed. This showed me that I installed the provider correct (Simply because it was there), however it was the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client one, and NOT the Oracle.DataAccess.Client one... All the SO posts and the internet never told me about this Managed one...

So that made it a simple fix by adding that Oracle.ManagedDataAccess dll, set copylocal to false and a reference to it to the application (in the GAC would be possible too I guess) and changing the connectionstring providerName-attribute in the web.config to

```
providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
```

Should you not have an OracleProvider in the dataTable but you're certain you installed it, it is possible it didn't get added to your machine.config. You can add it to your web.config  root:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="ODP.NET Managed Driver"
           invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
           description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
           type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess,
           Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

(Guess that could also be used to deploy it on a machine without the Provider dll's, as long as you deploy the Dll along with the application)

Hopefully this will help a future visitor!